# Highcharts Series - want to show/hide all EXCEPT selected series (reversal of default logic)

Tags: highcharts

By default Highcharts allows you to click on a data series set to hide it / unhide it.

A much more useful approach would be to do the reverse logic - ie to show only the selected series and hide/unhide the non-selected.

Looking at the example here ( http://jsfiddle.net/t2MxW/14/ ), it is clear one can 'intercept' the the 'legendItemClick' event, I am just not sure how to implement the require logic

One can replace the below script to obtain 3 data sets.

DESIRED SCENARIO: to be able to click on 'apples' and show/hide 'pears' and 'oranges' for example.

================= PASTE START =======================================

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function(event) {
                    var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
                    if (!confirm('The series is currently '+ 
                                 visibility +'. Do you want to change that?')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series:[{name: 'apples',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]},
    {name:'pears',
    data: [19.9, 81.5, 96.4, 119.2, 124.0, 166.0, 155.6, 138.5, 116.4, 144.1, 95.6, 54.4]},

           {name:'oranges',
    data: [119.9, 181.5, 46.4, 219.2, 24.0, 66.0, 255.6, 238.5, 16.4, 44.1, 95.6, 54.4]}
           ]   

});
```

Answer (score 48):

Every event in HighCharts contains `this` value which contains current element (series in this case). You can select all series using `this.chart.series` and handle them in any way you want. Try this function.

```
legendItemClick: function(event) {
    if (!this.visible)
        return false;

    var seriesIndex = this.index;
    var series = this.chart.series;

    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
    {
        if (series[i].index != seriesIndex)
        {
            series[i].visible ?
            series[i].hide() :
            series[i].show();
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t2MxW/21971/

Comment: I see you have if (!this.visible) return true; This does not appear to work - I can click on a 'hidden' series.

Comment: FIXED -  if (!this.visible) return FALSE;  Thanks a million - solution is brilliant!! :)

Comment: It works, but super slow for a moderate number (n=20) of series

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to do something similar... I wanted to have it so that if you control-click (or cmd-click) a legend item, it would hide ALL OTHER items. (But leave normal clicks as their default behavior).

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function(e) {
                // Upon cmd-click of a legend item, rather than toggling visibility, we want to hide all other items.
                var hideAllOthers = e.browserEvent.metaKey;
                if (hideAllOthers) {
                    var seriesIndex = this.index;
                    var series = this.chart.series;

                    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
                        // rather than calling 'show()' and 'hide()' on the series', we use setVisible and then
                        // call chart.redraw --- this is significantly faster since it involves fewer chart redraws
                        if (series[i].index === seriesIndex) {
                            if (!series[i].visible) series[i].setVisible(true, false);
                        } else {
                            if (series[i].visible) series[i].setVisible(false, false);
                        }
                    }
                    this.chart.redraw();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks!
I used `e.browserEvent.metaKey || e.browserEvent.ctrlKey` to include Windows users

Comment: updated to include @satyadeepk addition https://jsfiddle.net/derekrezek/Nkeep/109/

Comment: Works perfectly even for large number of series. Thanks.

Comment: Is this behaviour built in at this point by any chance? This seems like it should be the default - it has a huge advantage (quick toggle of series) and zero disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

Just sharing cause @igor's answer doesn't work on me, so I made adjustments, here's the fiddle (forked from the @igor's answer)

http://jsfiddle.net/index/Nkeep/

Comment: I fixed the fiddle mentioned in this answer, with the new location for highcharts.js http://jsfiddle.net/philfreo/Nkeep/85/

Comment: @philfreo It would be better if we could see all data at the start and the be able to toggle.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the normal functionality but also be able to show/hide all then create a button or a link for a `show_all()`/`hide_all()` javascript method.

this method initializes a counter and starts the showing/hiding:

```
counter = 0;
setTimeout(process_hide, 1);

function process_hide()
{
    your_chart.series[counter].hide();
    counter+=1;
    if (counter < read_chart.series.length) {
        setTimeout(process_hide, 1);
    }
}
```

The reason you do this instead of just doing `$.each(your_chart, function(i,v){v.hide()})` is that it locks up the UI - using the timeout you'll actually see the series being hidden one by one - and if you want to modify something else - like a process meter, it'll actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Forked index's answer and added functionality to have individual toggles for each series. http://jsfiddle.net/c4Zd8/1/

```
$.each(allSeries, function(index, series) {
    if (selected == index) {
        if (series.visible == true) {
            series.hide();
        }
        else {
            series.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: aren't you just replicating the built in functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Forked because I wanted behavior to change.  Originally when a user selected two series and then tried to unselect one ... the whole series would swap visibility.  I check to see if all other series are "all else visibile" or "all else not visible" first before swapping the visibility for the series.

http://jsfiddle.net/nd0dcdmz/3/

```
legendItemClick: function(e) {
    var seriesIndex = this.index;
    var series = this.chart.series;

    // test for if all other series besides one selected are visible or not visible
    var allElseVisible = series.every(
      s => (s.index == seriesIndex ? true : s.visible),
    );
    var allElseNotVisible = series.every(
      s => (s.index == seriesIndex ? true : !s.visible),
    );

    // if everything else is deselected or selected ... swap visibility
    // else swap the visibility of selected object.
    if (allElseVisible || allElseNotVisible) {
      series.map(s => {
        if (s.index != seriesIndex) {
          s.visible ? s.hide() : s.show();
        }
      });
    } else {
      return true;
    }

    return false; // overrides default behavior
},
```