# Highcharts: reverse the legend filter on a scatter plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts has a really nice filtering feature where the chart renders, shows the legend, and you can click on each item in the legend to remove it from the chart. I'm working with a large data set and would like to do the reverse (ie, instead of removing the item that's been clicked in the legend, leaving all the others, I'd like to show ONLY that item, removing all the others)

Although there are StackOverflow entries such as [Highcharts Series - want to show/hide all EXCEPT selected series (reversal of default logic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608410/highcharts-series-want-to-show-hide-all-except-selected-series-reversal-of-de) that look perfect (and run in jsfiddle), I'm working with a scatterplot. Looking at the documentation, it appears it should still work as scatter uses series, events & legendItemClick, but the sample from that answer doesn't work.

Even something as simple as...

```js
plotOptions: {
  scatter: {
    marker: {
      radius: c.data.radius,
      states: {
        hover: {
            enabled: true,
            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
        }
      }
    },
    series: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function(event) {
          console.log('legend clicked')
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...doesn't work (although the chart displays properly). There's no message in the console and the return false doesn't stop the default behavior. It seems as though legendItemClick isn't recognized by scatter plots.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: But the documentation shows an example working fine... hmmm... I'll give there example a try in my report
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-legenditemclick/

Comment: Shouldn't the `series` key be outside of `scatter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example how to implement required behavior in Highcharts `scatter` chart:

```
    legendItemClick: function(event) {
      var series = this.chart.series,
        index = this.index;

      if (this.visible) {
        return false

      } else {
        Highcharts.each(series, function(s) {
          if (s.index !== index) {
            s.hide();
          } else {
            return true
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/45e01r78/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've got it working so that it shows/hides correctly, but it is incredibly slow (taking 20-30 seconds) as I have 30+ in the series (hence my desire to filter like this). I suspect it's because the .show() and .hide() are rendering each time. It would be nice if I could set visible to true/false for each series and then simply redraw once, but I couldn't figure that bit out.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the chart is redrawing for each series, please try this code: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/93yd6mck/

Comment: Ah, that's it.... thank you very much... I've modified the code slightly so that the behavior is:
* All series display on open
* All but the series selected are hidden "on click"
* User can click on other legend items to show just them
* If the user clicks the one visible series item the chart reverts to showing all
Thanks
https://jsfiddle.net/pcawdron/h5ogcynz/37/

Answer (score -1):

You can easily meet your requirements using FusionCharts where you could just filter the series using a single attribute using  "visible":"0" at the dataset level for that series which will disable the legend, and when you can enable that series by just clicking the legend, further you could also customize the legends, you could reverse the order of the legends, you could also invoke legend item click rollover like events, thus making it really easy for the legend management, here is a sample snippet for the same

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdovhec6/)

```
 FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var tempVsSalesChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'scatter',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '600',
    height: '350',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Sales of Beer & Ice-cream vs Temperature",
        "subCaption": "Los Angeles Topanga",
        "xAxisName": "Average Day Temperature",
        "yAxisName": "Sales (In USD)",
        "xAxisMinValue": "23",
        "xAxisMaxValue": "95",
        "yNumberPrefix": "$",
        "xNumberSuffix": "&deg; F",
        "showYAxisLine": "1",
        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "verticalLineDashed": "1",
        "verticalLineDashLen": "1",
        "verticalLineDashGap": "1",
        "verticalLineThickness": "1",
        "verticalLineColor": "#000000",
        "category": [{
            "x": "23",
            "label": "23\xB0 F",
            "showverticalline": "0"
          },
          {
            "x": "32",
            "label": "32\xB0 F",
            "showverticalline": "1"
          },
          {
            "x": "50",
            "label": "50\xB0 F",
            "showverticalline": "1"
          },
          {
            "x": "68",
            "label": "68\xB0 F",
            "showverticalline": "1"
          },
          {
            "x": "80",
            "label": "80\xB0 F",
            "showverticalline": "1"
          },
          {
            "x": "95",
            "label": "95\xB0 F",
            "showverticalline": "1"
          }
        ]
      }],
      "dataset": [{
        "seriesname": "Ice Cream",
        "visible": "0",
        "showregressionline": "1",
        "data": [{
            "x": "23",
            "y": "1560"
          },
          {
            "x": "24",
            "y": "1500"
          },
          {
            "x": "24",
            "y": "1680"
          },
          {
            "x": "25",
            "y": "1780"
          },
          {
            "x": "25",
            "y": "1620"
          },
          {
            "x": "26",
            "y": "1810"
          },
          {
            "x": "27",
            "y": "2310"
          },
          {
            "x": "29",
            "y": "2620"
          },
          {
            "x": "31",
            "y": "2500"
          },
          {
            "x": "32",
            "y": "2410"
          },
          {
            "x": "35",
            "y": "2880"
          },
          {
            "x": "36",
            "y": "3910"
          },
          {
            "x": "34",
            "y": "3960"
          },
          {
            "x": "38",
            "y": "4080"
          },
          {
            "x": "40",
            "y": "4190"
          },
          {
            "x": "41",
            "y": "4170"
          },
          {
            "x": "42",
            "y": "4280"
          },
          {
            "x": "54",
            "y": "5180"
          },
          {
            "x": "53",
            "y": "5770"
          },
          {
            "x": "55",
            "y": "5900"
          },
          {
            "x": "56",
            "y": "5940"
          },
          {
            "x": "58",
            "y": "6090"
          },
          {
            "x": "61",
            "y": "6086"
          },
          {
            "x": "67",
            "y": "6100"
          },
          {
            "x": "68",
            "y": "6200"
          },
          {
            "x": "70",
            "y": "6360"
          },
          {
            "x": "75",
            "y": "6450"
          },
          {
            "x": "79",
            "y": "6650"
          },
          {
            "x": "80",
            "y": "6710"
          },
          {
            "x": "79",
            "y": "6975"
          },
          {
            "x": "82",
            "y": "7000"
          },
          {
            "x": "85",
            "y": "7150"
          },
          {
            "x": "86",
            "y": "7160"
          },
          {
            "x": "86",
            "y": "7200"
          },
          {
            "x": "88",
            "y": "7230"
          },
          {
            "x": "87",
            "y": "7210"
          },
          {
            "x": "86",
            "y": "7480"
          },
          {
            "x": "89",
            "y": "7540"
          },
          {
            "x": "89",
            "y": "7400"
          },
          {
            "x": "90",
            "y": "7500"
          },
          {
            "x": "92",
            "y": "7640"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "seriesname": "Beer",
        "showregressionline": "1",
        "data": [{
            "x": "23",
            "y": "3160"
          },
          {
            "x": "24",
            "y": "3000"
          },
          {
            "x": "24",
            "y": "3080"
          },
          {
            "x": "25",
            "y": "3680"
          },
          {
            "x": "25",
            "y": "3320"
          },
          {
            "x": "26",
            "y": "3810"
          },
          {
            "x": "27",
            "y": "5310"
          },
          {
            "x": "29",
            "y": "3620"
          },
          {
            "x": "31",
            "y": "4100"
          },
          {
            "x": "32",
            "y": "3910"
          },
          {
            "x": "35",
            "y": "4280"
          },
          {
            "x": "36",
            "y": "4210"
          },
          {
            "x": "34",
            "y": "4160"
          },
          {
            "x": "38",
            "y": "4480"
          },
          {
            "x": "40",
            "y": "4890"
          },
          {
            "x": "41",
            "y": "4770"
          },
          {
            "x": "42",
            "y": "4880"
          },
          {
            "x": "54",
            "y": "4980"
          },
          {
            "x": "53",
            "y": "4770"
          },
          {
            "x": "55",
            "y": "4900"
          },
          {
            "x": "56",
            "y": "4940"
          },
          {
            "x": "58",
            "y": "4990"
          },
          {
            "x": "61",
            "y": "5086"
          },
          {
            "x": "67",
            "y": "5100"
          },
          {
            "x": "68",
            "y": "4700"
          },
          {
            "x": "70",
            "y": "5360"
          },
          {
            "x": "75",
            "y": "5150"
          },
          {
            "x": "79",
            "y": "5450"
          },
          {
            "x": "80",
            "y": "5010"
          },
          {
            "x": "79",
            "y": "4975"
          },
          {
            "x": "82",
            "y": "5400"
          },
          {
            "x": "85",
            "y": "5150"
          },
          {
            "x": "86",
            "y": "5460"
          },
          {
            "x": "86",
            "y": "5000"
          },
          {
            "x": "88",
            "y": "5200"
          },
          {
            "x": "87",
            "y": "5410"
          },
          {
            "x": "86",
            "y": "5480"
          },
          {
            "x": "89",
            "y": "5440"
          },
          {
            "x": "89",
            "y": "5300"
          },
          {
            "x": "90",
            "y": "5500"
          },
          {
            "x": "92",
            "y": "5240"
          }
        ]
      }],
      "vtrendlines": [{
        "line": [{
            "startvalue": "23",
            "endvalue": "32",
            "istrendzone": "1",
            "displayvalue": " ",
            "color": "#adebff",
            "alpha": "25"
          },
          {
            "startvalue": "23",
            "endvalue": "32",
            "istrendzone": "1",
            "alpha": "0",
            "displayvalue": "Very cold"
          },
          {
            "startvalue": "32",
            "endvalue": "50",
            "istrendzone": "1",
            "displayvalue": " ",
            "color": "#adebff",
            "alpha": "15"
          }, {
            "startvalue": "32",
            "endvalue": "50",
            "istrendzone": "1",
            "alpha": "0",
            "displayvalue": "Cold"
          },
          {
            "startvalue": "50",
            "endvalue": "68",
            "istrendzone": "1",
            "alpha": "0",
            "displayvalue": "Moderate"
          },
          {
            "startvalue": "68",
            "endvalue": "80",
            "istrendzone": "1",
            "alpha": "0",
            "displayvalue": "Hot"
          },
          {
            "startvalue": "68",
            "endvalue": "80",
            "istrendzone": "1",
            "displayvalue": " ",
            "color": "#f2a485",
            "alpha": "15"
          },
          {
            "startvalue": "80",
            "endvalue": "95",
            "istrendzone": "1",
            "alpha": "0",
            "displayvalue": "Very hot"
          },
          {
            "startvalue": "80",
            "endvalue": "95",
            "istrendzone": "1",
            "displayvalue": " ",
            "color": "#f2a485",
            "alpha": "25"
          }
        ]
      }]
    },
    events: {
      "legendItemClicked": function(eventObj) {
        console.log(eventObj.sender);
      }
    }
  });

  tempVsSalesChart.render();
});
```

To know more about FusionCharts legends check this [link](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/legend#main-content-wrapper)